# TClError while using TkinterDnD2 module with customtkinter framework

Tags: tkinter, drag-and-drop, edit, text-editor, customtkinter

Recently I tried integrating drag and drop to my app. But when I debuged my program, I got an error, saying "_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name "tkdnd::drop_target". Here is full code:

```
import tkinter, customtkinter 
from TkinterDnD2 import *

def show_text(event):
    textarea.delete("1.0","end")
    if event.data.endswith(".txt"):
    with open(event.data, "r") as file:
        for line in file:
            line=line.strip()
            textarea.insert("end",f"{line}\n")

ws = customtkinter.CTk()
ws.title('PythonGuides')
ws.geometry('400x300')
ws.config(bg='#fcb103')

frame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(ws)
frame.pack()

textarea = customtkinter.CTkTextbox(frame, height=18, width=40)
textarea.pack(side=tkinter.LEFT)
textarea.drop_target_register(DND_FILES)
textarea.dnd_bind('<<Drop>>', show_text)

ws.mainloop()
```

I don't know why it occurred, maybe customtkinter doesn't support Dnd, just like tk.call() method.

Comment: Are you sure you are using `TkinterDnD2` correctly? From what I remember, aren't you supposed to use `TkinterDnD.Tk` for the window? Check a working sample that uses `TkinterDnD2`. Also you should check if `customtkinter` plays nice with `TkinterDnD2` as they are separate libraries (as far as I know) and might not work well together.

Comment: It worked, but what to do with styling, I mean dark theme. And how to use it with OOP?

Comment: I don't get what you mean by *"how to use it with OOP"*. If you want `customtkinter`'s styling, you will have a hard time (nearly impossible). You can try to look at the source code for both `customtkinter.Tk` and `TkinterDnD.Tk` and try to combine them. It will probably result in an undebuggable mess.

Comment: I meant 'how to use it with OOP' by making a class, which inherits TkinterDnD.Tk class.

Comment: To make a class that the inherits from `TkinterDnD.Tk` use `class MyClassName(TkinterDnD.Tk): ...`. It's nothing unusual. If you are still unsure about it, look up some python OOP tutorials.

Comment: I know, but it shows me same error as before

Comment: "_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name "tkdnd::drop_target"